# How to enter the date you want in a .bat file

Tags: csv, batch-file

So I have a .vbs file that converts an .xlsx file into an .csv file. I made a short .bat file that opens automatically the cmd and runs it without having to manually enter the command.

```
set "curpath=%cd%"

start conv.vbs %curpath%\file_date.xlsx %curpath%\Destination_date.csv
```

How can I modify it in order to manually introduce a date, when running the .bat that takes the source file as file_date(you introduced) and creates a Destination_date(you introduced).csv ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `UserDate` variable via prompt where [Variable]=[Prompt]

```
set /p CurrentDate=Enter existing date here:
set /p NewDate=Enter new date here:
```

then update your conv.vbs to take another parameter:

```
set "curpath=%cd%"

start conv.vbs %curpath%\%CurrentDate%.xlsx %curpath%\%NewDate%.csv
```

- the `/p` flag tells the batch file to prompt the user
- the value on the left side of the equal sign is the name of the variable your setting
- the value on the right side of the equal sign is the message you are prompting the user with
- The variables are referenced by surrounding the variable name with % ... %

Comment: I don't really understand how it works. Don't have much experience with this bat files. This only creates a kind of pop up that you can enter anything in it, doesn't replace my source file in the path.

Comment: My apologies -- i read your question wrong, please see the updated answer above.